# Turning a form into a URL

Tags: javascript, html, forms

I'd like to be able to grab the result of an HTML form submission using wget (or equivalently curl). Instead of clicking on ".csv" in [this control](http://www.ifpsglobal.com/Identification/PLU-Codes/PLU-codes-Search):

[image]

I want to be able to type something like:

```
% wget http://www.example.com/export?code1=1&code2=9999&format=csv
```

(or the curl equivalent). I'm having trouble figuring out how to turn the HTML + JavaScript into the URL that gets submitted when the form executes. It's a GET, so the form itself is ultimately generating a URL, but I can't figure out how it's being constructed.

The basic layout, including the fields that I'm interested in, is:

```
<form method="GET">
   <input name="code1" type="text" value="">
   <input name="code1" type="text" value="">
   <button type="submit">Search</button>
   <button type="button" aria-expanded="false">
      Export <span class="caret"></span>
   </button>
   <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
       <li><a href="#" rel="xlsx">.xlsx</a></li>
       <li><a href="#" rel="xls">.xls</a></li>
       <li><a href="#" rel="csv">.csv</a></li>
   </ul>
</form>
```

I'd like to compose a URL that's equivalent to filling in the `code1` and `code2` inputs, then clicking on the ".csv" link in the dropdown (`<ul>`). I don't understand what the `rel` attribute does, and how it contributes to the URL that's constructed.

[Here](http://www.ifpsglobal.com/Identification/PLU-Codes/PLU-codes-Search) is the page containing the original code. The form in question is in the frame containing "Search".

Comment: Something like that?

`http://check.ifpsglobal.com/widget/export/csv?token=4ZYrVflLPK6p&action=search&q=&code1=&code2=&category=&commodity_search=&variety_search=&gpc=`

Comment: The code for the export is in the HTML for the `iframe`. All it is doing is serializing the form parameters and redirecting them to the location: `http://check.ifpsglobal.com/widget/export/csv?params` where `csv` and `params` are replaced with your values.

Comment: I'm having trouble understanding where "export" comes from in the URL. Is it placed there in JS?

Answer (score 0):

If you use jQuery, then you can simply call `serialize()` on the form.

Otherwise, you'll have to build the string yourself. You can find all the details here: http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/interact/forms.html#h-17.13

The short version is that the URL is:

- the "action" of the form, which defaults to the current document URL, minus the query part (`?` and anything that follows it), and of course minus the fragment (`#` and anything that follows it).
- `?`
- the various fields, in `name=value` format, separated by `&`
- names and values must be URL-encoded first (which means replacing quite a few things by %xy sequences, and spaces by +)